# Mostrar relacionados de tres tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo cuatro tablas la primera seria:

La tabla "articulos" esta tabla solo tiene id_articulos, descripcioncorta, archivo, id_estatus.

La tabla "imagenes" la cual va a contener el id_imagenes y la localización de la imágenes, la tabla.

La tabla "textos" la cual contiene el id_textos y el texto como tal.

Todo esto lo enlazo con una tabla que se llama "posicion" en la cual guardo el id_posicion, el id_imagenes, el id_textos y la posición

Intento de hacer un Query que me traiga todas las imágenes y todos los textos que existen con el id de un articulo pero me lo duplica, aquí el Query que intente

```
SELECT localizacion,texto from imagenes,textos WHERE id_imagenes IN 
    (SELECT id_imagenes FROM posicion WHERE id_articulos = 1) AND id_textos IN 
    (SELECT id_textos FROM posicion WHERE id_articulos = 1)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no poner una relacion entre las tablas imagenes y textos va a hacer un producto cartesiano entre las mismas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base al Query que escribiste, esta es la forma mas correcta que encontré de hacer lo que necesitas:

```
 SELECT i.localicacion,t.texto FROM posicion p 
 INNER JOIN imagenes i ON i.id_imagenes = p.id_imagenes
 INNER JOIN textos t ON t.id_textos = p.id_textos
```

La tabla posición es la encargada de enlazar tus tablas, en base a sus id's hago los joins correspondientes para así acceder a la información de todas tus tablas.

Comment: lo resolví con otra tabla de base de datos jaja un saludo!